# Save next 32 bytes in hex (after search)

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, hex

I am searching all files on my drive for a given hexadecimal value, after it is found I need to copy and save the next 32 bytes after the found occurrence (there may be many occurrences in one file).

Right now I'm searching for files like this:

```
ggrep -obaRUP "\x01\x02\x03\x04" . > outputfile.txt
```

But this script retuns only file path. Preferably I'd like to use only standard Linux / Mac tools.

Comment: With `ggrep` you mean [this](https://github.com/aalemayhu/ggrep), don't you?

Comment: No, it's just a grep installed on mac over homebrew. Grep on mac needs te be installed separately from coreutils 
[here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/grep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-P` (`--perl-regexes`) you can use the `\K` escape sequence to clear the matching buffer. Then match `.{32}` more chars(!):

```
LANG=C grep -obaRUP "\x01\x02\x03\x04\K.{32,32}" . > output.file
```

Note:

- I'm using `LANG=C` to enforce a locale which is using single byte encoding, not utf-8. This is to make sure `.{32}` would not accidentally match unicode chars(!), but bytes instead.
- The `-P` option is only supported by GNU grep (along with a few others used in your example)
- You may want to open the output.file in a hex editor to actually see characters. For example `hexdump`, `hd` or `xxd` could be used.

---

Note, the above command will additionally print the filename and the line number / byte offset of the match. This is implicitly caused by using `grep -R (recursive)`.

To get only the 32 bytes in the output, and nothing else, I suggest to use `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -oaUP '\x01\x02\x03\x04\K.{32}' {} \;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns empty output. I'm using mac if thet changes anything (brew installed grep). 
But I realized it should be like this:  ```
grep -obaRUP "\x01\x02\x03\x04\K.{0,32}" . > output.file
```
But my problem is - it returns file names I just want that 32 bytes in ascii in each line

Comment: Dude, that's an awesome trick I did *not* know. I'm stealing it, lol

Comment: @Mackos `grep -h` == no filename.. That's simple. However, in recursive mode, there is no way to disable the line numbers.. I suggest to use `find ... -exec grep ...` .. Added example

Comment: @PaulHodges no worries :)

Comment: Huh. On my Git Bash emulation it's not giving me line numbers.

Comment: Not ideal, but close enough - so I mark it as correct one

Comment: Hey! What's your ideal solution? I get that you want only the 32 bytes. Do you want to print a separator between multiple results? Or no separator?

Answer (score 1):

My test was a little simple, but this worked for me.

```
$: IFS=: read -r file offset data <<< "$(grep -obaRUP "\x01\x02\x03\x04.{32}" .)"
$: echo "$file @ $((offset+4)):[${data#????}]"
./x @ 10:[HERE ARE THE THIRTY-TWO BYTES !!]
```

Rather than do a complicated look-behind, I just gabbed the ^A^B^C^D *and* the next 32 bytes, and stripped off the leading 4 bytes from the field.

@hek2mgl's `\K` makes all that unnecessary, though. Use `-h` to eliminate filenames.

```
$: grep -obahRUP "\x01\x02\x03\x04\K.{32}" .
10:HERE ARE THE THIRTY-TWO BYTES !!
```

Take out the `-b` if you don't want the offset.

```
$: grep -oahRUP "\x01\x02\x03\x04\K.{32}" .
HERE ARE THE THIRTY-TWO BYTES !!
```